# Conditional attributes in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Does Terraform support conditional attributes? I only want to use an attribute depending on a variable's value.

Example:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "my_volume" {
  availability_zone = "xyz"
  size              = 30

  if ${var.staging_mode} == true:
    snapshot_id = "a_specific_snapshot_id"
  endif
}
```

The above `if` statement enclosing the attribute `snapshot_id` is what I'm looking for. Does Terraform support such attribute inclusion based on a variable's value.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Terraform 0.12 (yet to be released) will also bring [support for HCL2](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-1-2-preview) which allows you to use [nullable arguments](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#null) with something like this:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "my_volume" {
  availability_zone = "xyz"
  size              = 30
  snapshot_id       = var.staging_mode ? local.a_specific_snapshot_id : null
}
```

Nullable arguments are covered in [this 0.12 preview guide](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements#conditionally-omitted-arguments).

For version of Terraform before 0.12, [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4210388/markus)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497455/2291321) is probably your best bet although I'd be more explicit with the `count` with something like this:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "staging_volume" {
   count             = "${var.staging_mode ? 1 : 0}"
   availability_zone = "xyz"
   size              = 30

   snapshot_id = "a_specific_snapshot_id"
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "non_staging_volume" {
   count             = "${var.staging_mode ? 0 : 1}"
   availability_zone = "xyz"
   size              = 30
}
```

Note that the resource names must be unique or Terraform will complain. This then causes issues if you need to refer to the EBS volume such as with an `aws_volume_attachment` as in [pre 0.12 the ternary expression is not lazy](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements#conditional-operator-improvements) so something like this doesn't work:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = "${var.staging_mode ? aws_ebs_volume.staging_volume.id : aws_ebs_volume.non_staging_volume.id}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.web.id}"
}
```

Because it will attempt to evaluate both sides of the ternary where only one can be valid at any point. In Terraform 0.12 this will no longer be the case but obviously you could solve it more easily with the nullable arguments.

Comment: You can get around the laziness by using `join`, see also my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497455/4210388).

Answer (score 11):

I'm not aware of such a feature, however, you can model around this, if your cases are not too complicated. Since the Boolean values `true` and `false` are considered to be `1` and `0`, you can use them within a count. So you may use

```
provider "null" {}

resource "null_resource" "test1" {
   count= ${var.condition ? 1 : 0}
}
resource "null_resource" "test2" {
   count = ${var.condition ? 0 : 1}
}

output "out" {
    value = "${var.condition ? join(",",null_resource.test1.*.id) : join(",",null_resource.test2.*.id) }"
}
```

Only one of the two resources is created due to the `count` attribute.

You have to use `join` for the values, because this seems to handle the inexistence of one of the two values gracefully.

Thanks [ydaetskcor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291321/ydaetskcor) for pointing out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51498185/4210388) the improvements for variable handling.

Comment: I dont think this will work since you are having two resources with the same name "my_volume"

Comment: @BasilMusa I corrected the code accordingly, adding a workaround to still access values from the resources.

Comment: Yes, but now a new problem comes up, toggling will destroy test1 and create test2. A conditional attribute should be able to handle updating a resource. Anyway, good tip and useful in certain cases. I'll upvote.

Comment: Without testing it, I would assume that if you just insert the `snapshot_id` and do a plan again, this would also recreate the resource. But you are right, this method has this drawback, even for in-place updatable attributes. You may have to wait for the new version of HCL (as ydaetskcoR mentioned).

Answer (score 10):

Now that Terraform v0.12 and respective HCL2 were released, you can achieve this by just setting the default variable value to "null". Look at this example from Terraform website:

```html
variable "override_private_ip" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ... (other aws_instance arguments) ...

  private_ip = var.override_private_ip
}
```

More info here:

https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements

Answer (score 1):

There is a new experimental feature with Terraform 0.15 : [`defaults`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/defaults.html) which works with `optional`.

> The defaults function is a specialized function intended for use with input variables whose type constraints are object types or collections of object types that include optional attributes.

From documentation :

```
terraform {
  # Optional attributes and the defaults function are
  # both experimental, so we must opt in to the experiment.
  experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
}

variable "storage" {
  type = object({
    name    = string
    enabled = optional(bool)
    website = object({
      index_document = optional(string)
      error_document = optional(string)
    })
    documents = map(
      object({
        source_file  = string
        content_type = optional(string)
      })
    )
  })
}

locals {
  storage = defaults(var.storage, {
    # If "enabled" isn't set then it will default
    # to true.
    enabled = true

    # The "website" attribute is required, but
    # it's here to provide defaults for the
    # optional attributes inside.
    website = {
      index_document = "index.html"
      error_document = "error.html"
    }

    # The "documents" attribute has a map type,
    # so the default value represents defaults
    # to be applied to all of the elements in
    # the map, not for the map itself. Therefore
    # it's a single object matching the map
    # element type, not a map itself.
    documents = {
      # If _any_ of the map elements omit
      # content_type then this default will be
      # used instead.
      content_type = "application/octet-stream"
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just for the help, a more complex example:

```
data "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count             = var.sk_count
  vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = element(sort(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names), count.index)

  tags = {
    Name = var.old_cluster_fqdn != "" ? "${var.old_cluster_fqdn}-prv-subnet-${count.index}" : "${var.cluster_fqdn}-prv-subnet-${count.index}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I found this answer on Google and was quite confused by it I thought I better update the answer

The defaults() function used in the locals block no longer exists.

For my use-case I instead used the 2nd argument of optional.

```
variable "settings" {
  type = object({
    systemd_base = optional(string, "/etc/systemd/system")
  })
}
```